# Detect when taps are outside of a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am working on a program where I have various `UITextView`s. The problem I am having is that I cannot detect when the user has tapped outside of the `UITextView` so that I can hide the keyboard. I have tried various actions, but none of them work.

Code I am using with actions:

```
@IBAction func touchOutsideTextField(sender: UITextField)
{
    sender.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

What should I be doing to hide the keyboard instead of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` For that.

add TapGesture into View and when View is tapped that time keyBoard will hide.

Here is the sample code for you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var text3: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var text4: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let aSelector : Selector = "touchOutsideTextField"
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func touchOutsideTextField(){

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

}
```

Or you can use `touchesBegan` method for it add this code if you want to try this way.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

With this code you don't need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

You can choose one of this option.

Answer (score 0):

For those still using Obj C here is the translation:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}
```

Apple says in their documentation that if you omit the call to super, then you must also override the other touch methods...even if you don't use them.  For more on that here is the link: [touchesBegan:withEvent:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan?language=objc)